# How to apply appearance none property in IE9 & Firefox?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, firefox

Is it possible to apply `appearance` property in `IE9` & `Firefox` ?

Comment: [Browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

For CSS (as for any other widespread language), there is an official documentation. Additionally, there are many resources repeating or interpreting this documentation, e.g.,  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp. As you can see, IE no, Firefox nearly.

Please have a look at those sites before asking this.